# Use single pattern to string match multiple words Lua script

Tags: linux, lua, ubuntu-14.04

I have simple text as below:

```
Hello World [all 1]
Hi World [words 2]
World World [are 3]
Hello Hello [different 4]
```

I want set all words in the square bracket as the variable in array using Lua.
I try this code below:

```
text = 'Hello World [all 1]\nHi World [words 2]\nWorld World [are 3]\nHello Hello [different 4]'

array = {string.match(text, '[%a%s]*%[([%a%s%d]*)%]')}

for i = 1,#array do
print(array[i])
end
```

The output is  "all 1". My objective is to printout output as

```
all 1
words 2
are 3
different 4
```

I have tried to add 3 same patterns as below:

```
array = {string.match(text, '[%a%s]*%[([%a%s%d]*)%].-[%a%s]*%[([%a%s%d]*)%].-[%a%s]*%[([%a%s%d]*)%].-[%a%s]*%[([%a%s%d]*)%]')}
```

It is working. But I don't think it is the best way especially when the text have load of lines like 100, etc. What is the proper way to do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these lines in a file, or is it a single string that you want to search?

Comment: thank you for prompt reply. it is a single string that contains all the words above.

Comment: `array = {}
for s in s:gmatch '%b[]' do array[#array+1] = s:sub(2,-2) end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua patterns [do not support repeated captures](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), but you can use `string.gmatch()`, which returns an iterator function, with an input string, using the pattern `"%[(.-)%]"` to capture the desired text:

```
text = 'Hello World [all 1]\nHi World [words 2]\nWorld World [are 3]\nHello Hello [different 4]'

local array = {}
for capture in string.gmatch(text, "%[(.-)%]") do
   table.insert(array, capture)
end

for i = 1, #array do
   print(array[i])
end
```

The above code gives output:

```
all 1
words 2
are 3
different 4
```

Note that this can be done in a single line, if desired:

```
array = {} for c in string.gmatch(text, "%[(.-)]") do table.insert(array, c) end
```

Also note that there is no need to escape an isolated closing bracket, as this final example demonstrates.